# Counting the total number of categorial values in a column for an entire dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

(I am certain this is a repeat question---I am sorry I cannot figure this out.)

I have hundreds of *csv files whereby I would like to count the categorical variables of one column. Thankfully, these files have already been cleaned up such that they have the save format. An example file of the tabular format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7"], 
                   "column2" : ["element_A", "element_A", "element_B", "element_A", "element_B", "element_B", "element_A"],
                   "column3" : ["item22", "item6", "item7", "item42", "item49", "item91", "item3"],
                   "column4" : ["abc", "edf", "edf", "abc", "edf", "xyz", "abc"]})
df = df[["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]]


df
```

outputs

```
    column1 column2     column3 column4
0   value1  element_A   item22  abc
1   value2  element_A   item6   edf
2   value3  element_B   item7   edf
3   value4  element_A   item42  abc
4   value5  element_B   item49  edf
5   value6  element_B   item91  xyz
6   value7  element_A   item3   abc
```

For each file, I would like to count the number of items in `column4', and output these statistics for each file in a "master table", one filename for each row, e.g.

```
            abc    def    xyz
filename1   3      3      1
filename2   42     0      7 
filename3   0      16     4
filename4   4      71     21
....
```

My approach would be to `glob` each of the filenames and then count using `groupby`. However, I'm running into an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

final = pd.Dataframe()
files = glob.glob("*.csv")
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_table(filename)
    df["filename"] = str(filename)
    df = df.groupby("column4").count().unstack("column4").fillna(0).astype(int)
    final = final.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Naturally, there's a mistake here:

```
 df = df.groupby("column4").count().unstack("column4").fillna(0).astype(int)
```

As this will count the values for each column within `df`

```
         column4
column1  abc        3
         edf        3
         xyz        1
column2  abc        3
         edf        3
         xyz        1
column3  abc        3
         edf        3
         xyz        1
dtype: int64
```

What is the n00b mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `value_counts`, something like this:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_table(filename)
    new_row = df['column4'].value_counts().set_value('filename', filename)
    final = final.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```